# Method called by other method with setInterval can not access object property in js

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I wrote a object constructor function with two methods, one of them calls the other via setInterval(functionName, interval), and the called function fails to get the objects properties.

I wrote a simple example on codepen: http://codepen.io/AttilaVM/pen/ZQPVEy

```
function Test(value) {
    this.value = value

    this.action = function testAction() {
        console.log(this.value); // gives undefined!
    }

    this.play = function testPlay() {
        setInterval(this.action, 500);
    }
}

var test = new Test(20);
test.play();
```

If the method is called without setInterval it works as expected. Why is it different? How can the called method access the object's properties?

Comment: @Quentin, you are right about the duplication. I am pretty new in js so I was not able to search well enough to find that thread. Can I accept somehow that my question is indeed a duplicate?

Comment: No, if it is closed then it is closed and that is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `this` refers to `window` as it is being call in `setInterval(window.setInterval)`

To pass the current context, Use [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), *The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value*

```js
function Test(value) {
  this.value = value

  this.action = function testAction() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }

  this.play = function testPlay() {
    setInterval(this.action.bind(this), 500);
  }
}

var test = new Test(20);
test.play();
```